# TapkuLibrary error

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded `TapkuLibrary` and try to run it on Xcode Excepted ':' appear in two places how can i fix it

[image]

```
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame symbol:(id)symbol normalType:(TKInputKeyType)normal selectedType:(TKInputKeyType)highlighted runner:(BOOL)runner NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;


- (instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace please

Comment: excepted ':' in this two line of code only

Comment: Tried to comment the "NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER"

Comment: no visible @interface for initWithStyle

Comment: You will need to remove `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` from the method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure the answer

it is the attribute

```
__attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
```

so i must define it in my pch

```
#ifndef NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
#else
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#endif
#endif
```

so i can use it in xCode 5